# Unable access my website after Azure AD authentication enabled

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have installed a WebApp with plane code ( no extra code).

and I configured the AD authentication for a web app, and AD app-registration services there I provided the call-back URL"

everything configured as mentioned document but I'm facing the issue: "you don't have permission on this directory or page" when I open the "wwww.xyz.com".

I followed this, "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad".

Pls advise

Comment: Do you ever get redirected to the Azure AD login page first?

Comment: Maybe im not yang

Comment: You should see something similar to https://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/microsoft-sign-in.jpg. If you don't, then you may not have anonymous access enabled for the / or /account/ routing. What's the "plain" code that you're using (e.g. ASP.NET, .NET Core, nodejs... Visual Studio > File > New Project, git clone)?

Comment: How did you deploy your webapp to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you can access your website without enable App Service Authentication.

It is very easy to configure the AD authentication for a web app. You can [configure it with express settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings).

[image]

Remember to set **Action to take when request is not authenticated to Log in with Azure Active Directory**

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony, I have done the same you shared but didn't work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we got solution

we trace network log using Fiddler there we capture that

Error " xxxxx-- your subscription not subscribed the power.app  services and saying the please contact it admins"

solution:

we deselected the power.app service under the active directory

1. App registration
2. Api permissions
3. there are few optioned which are by default in one of that is power apps service we simply deleted that entry"

after that webapp authentication well.

TQ guys for ur support

Comment: Make it as answer, so this issue can be closed. Thank you.